# Remove and add connection string

Tags: .net, configuration

I want to remove a connection string that may already have been set in a different config file and then set it again.

Say my application has a Web.config file and a Web.Debug.config file then I can achieve what I want to do in the following way:

Web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="MyConnectionString" />
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="...";User Id=******;Password=******;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Web.Debug.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove xdt:Transform="Replace" name="MyConnectionString" />
    <add
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)"
      xdt:Locator="Condition(@name='MyConnectionString')"
      connectionString="...";User Id=******;Password=******;"
    />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am going to be removing connection strings and then adding them to ensure there are no errors that result from a connection string already having been set in some other config file. Before I change tens or hundreds of config files across all of our repositories I want to know if there is a better way - easier to read or requiring fewer/simpler changes.

Comment: Is there a reason you posted this question on Code Review rather than Stack Overflow? The question sounds very hypothetical and that would make it off-topic for code review.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I must have misunderstood what Code Review was for. I am looking for suggestions/improvements or reasons why the way I've proposed is not the way it's usually done. Is there a different channel for this type of question?

Comment: We review code that is working as expected. For future reference please read the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help). The question you are asking is about something that happens a lot in professional development. I had to modify a config file to point to the test database rather than the production database. I put all the code into git first so that I could back up to the original code when development was over. I don't know if there is really a good site for this question.

Comment: You might want to check Microsoft documentation and Q&A sites.

Comment: Please define *better way*. From what aspect?

Comment: @PeterCsala I've added details to improve the question.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I don't know what point you are making about reviewing code that is working as expected.

Comment: @Astrophe I think `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"` would be enough. You don't have to over specify it. Please bear in mind this approach might not work if you encrypt your `connectionStrings` section.

Comment: @PeterCsala Please can you format your comment into an answer. What I tried to do based on your comment resulted in the same error that I have seen before: The entry 'MyConnectionString' has already been added. But maybe I have not fully understood what you mean.

Comment: https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-transformations-the-definitive-syntax-guide/

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I have just finished discussing these changes with a colleague who pointed out that my Remove element transform in Web.Debug.config is not doing anything. The remove element in Web.config is all that is needed and it will be included in Web.Debug.config after it has been transformed. I'm relieved to know that the solution is a one-liner!

Answer (score 1):

Each `add` entry in `connectionStrings` section will be parsed as [ConnectionStringSettings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings) at the end of the day.
This class has 3 properties: `Name`,`ConnectionString` and `ProviderName`.

In your provided sample you have defined only the first two.

Your provided sample seems to me a bit too specific/strict:

- Replace only the `connectionStrings` attribute
- Match the entity where the name equals `MyConnectionString`

The same result could be achieved with less specific transformation rules:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <remove xdt:Transform="Replace" name="MyConnectionString" />
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="...;User Id=******;Password=123;" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

- I've specified the `name` as an attribute of the `add` element
- I've changed the `Locator` attribute value from `Condition` to `Match`
- And I've removed the `(connectionString)` suffix from the `Transform` attribute

I've checked the transformation with [this tool](https://elmah.io/tools/webconfig-transformation-tester/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these syntax improvements. It looks much better in this simplified form.